# SharePoint Permissions Re-provision PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, online, spo

I've created 2 scripts, one to export SharePoint Online permissions to a .CSV and one to re-provision SharePoint Online access.

I've come across a slight problem which is preventing the script from running successfully, the script to export SharePoint permissions lists the groups within one cell. When the re-provision script reads the input file (.csv) it errors because the script can't seem to read multiple values within the same cell.

Here's an example input:

https://TEST.sharepoint.com  test.user@test.com  Test Group 1 Test Group 2 Test Group 3

I've also tried separating the groups via special characters but this doesn't work either:

Test Group 1, Test Group 2, Test Group 3

This is my re-provision script so far:

```
Write-Host "---Start of Script $(Get-Date)"
Connect-SPOService -URL https://******-admin.sharepoint.com -credential *****@*****
$SPOUserImport = Import-csv "PATH"
foreach($ImportData in $SPOUserImport)
{
$field1 = $ImportData.Group
$field2 = $ImportData.Site
$field3 = $ImportData.User

Add-SPOUser -Group $field1 -Site $field2 -LoginName $field3 |Out-Null 
Write-Host "Added $field3 from .CSV to $field1, $field2" -ForegroundColor Green
}

Write-Host "---End of Script $(Get-Date)"
```

Any help appreciated!

Callum

Comment: $SPOUserImport = Import-csv "C:\Import.csv"
foreach($ImportData in $SPOUserImport)
{
$importGroups = $importData.group.split(",")
$field2 = $ImportData.Site
$field3 = $ImportData.User

Add-SPOUser -Group $importGroups[0] -Site $field2 -LoginName $field3 |Out-Null 
foreach($group in $importGroups[1..$($importGroups.count-1)])
     {
  Write-Host "Added $field3 from .CSV to $group, $field2" -ForegroundColor Green
     Add-SPOUser -Group $group -Site $field2 -LoginName $field3 |Out-Null
     }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are going to have is the way `import-csv` is handling your `group` column.

I'm assuming from your post where you say "lists the groups within one cell"your input file will look something like

```
site,user,group
https://test.sharepoint.com,test.user@test.com,Group1 Group2 Group3
```

The issue is that when you import that as a CSV your `$importData` array won't recognise the multiple group names as it's a single field.

You can test this by typing `$ImportData.group` at the prompt and observing the output, which will look something like :

`Group1 Group2 Group3`

What you will need to do is to turn that into it's own array

```
$importGroups = $importData.group.split(" ")
```

If you look at the content of the `$importGroups` array now you should have an element for each group.

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
```

You need to use this variable to iterate through the available groups and add each individually to the new user, so something like :

```
Add-SPOUser -Group $importGroups[0] -Site $field2 -LoginName $field3 |Out-Null 
foreach($group in $importGroups[1..$($importGroups.count-1)])
     {
     Add-SPOUser -Group $group -Site $field2 -LoginName $field3
     }
```

Please note this is untested but the theory should be sound.

Comment: That's great thank you Patrick! A quick amendment to the array format perfected my script.

Comment: Glad it worked! Can I ask that you paste your fully functioning script into your original post so future readers know exactly what worked for you?